# Match legend text labels with their correct fill colors in barplot

Tags: r, plot, legend

I am plotting a table with the values below:

| No | Sector | Amount USD (million) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Air Pollution | 134 |
| 2 | Water Resources | 3,158 |
| 3 | Land Use and Land Use Change | 91 |
| 4 | Biodiversity | 74 |
| 5 | Agriculture | 2,386 |
| 6 | Industry and Commerce | 528 |
| 7 | Mining | 312 |
| 8 | Tourism | 252 |
| 9 | Energy | 262 |
| 10 | Transport | 1,071 |
| 11 | Disaster Risk Management and Human Settlements | 519 |
| 12 | Waste Management | 231 |
| 13 | Health | 52 |
| 14 | Gender; People Living With HIV and AIDS and other Vulnerable groups | 25 |
| 15 | Children and Youth | 32 |
| 16 | Capacity Building | 45 |
| 17 | Role of Meteorological Services | 23 |
| 18 | Technology Transfer | 574 |
| 19 | Climate Change Education | 15 |
| 20 | Public Awareness | 15 |
| 21 | Climate Change Governance | 88 |

Once done, I put in the following code in R studio

```
#reading the table into R studio
zim5 <- read_excel ('zimbabwe-climate-finance-excel4.xlsx', col_names = TRUE)
zim5

#creating the objects for easier typing
sector1 <- zim5$Sector
sector1
millions1 <- zim5$'Amount USD (million)'
millions1

#finally plotting the barplot with a legend
mycol <- colors()[444:500]
barplot(millions1~sector1, width = 4, space = 0.2, main = 'Zimbabwe budget by sector', xlab = 'Economic sectors', ylab = 'Amount in US $ millions', 
        col = mycol, cex.names = 0.6, horiz = F, las = 2)
legend('top', sector1, fill = mycol, cex = 0.7, text.font = 3)
```

My aim was to get a barplot with a legend. However, although I managed to create the barplot (including a different one with horizontal bars (horiz = T and las = 1), my legend always seems to display the text labels in a different order than in the barplot in both. i.e., Air pollution corresponds with the fill of Agriculture in the graphic and so on. [image]

Though I noticed R studio seems to balance out the position of the bars according to their heights or something, I want the legend labels to correspond with their appropriate fill colours like in the x axis of the plot, whether or not R studio orders the bars differently from the table.

Comment: it probably adds them to the legend in the order that they appear in the data whereas barplot sorts them according to the label. You could try `legend('top', sort(sector1), ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Here it is - turning the label into a factor solves the problem.

```
z <- structure(list(no = 1:21, sector = c("Air Pollution", "Water Resources", 
                                          "Land Use and Land Use Change", "Biodiversity", "Agriculture", 
                                          "Industry and Commerce", "Mining", "Tourism", "Energy", "Transport", 
                                          "Disaster Risk Management and Human Settlements", "Waste Management", 
                                          "Health", "Gender; People Living With HIV and AIDS and other Vulnerable groups", 
                                          "Children and Youth", "Capacity Building", "Role of Meteorological Services", 
                                          "Technology Transfer", "Climate Change Education", "Public Awareness", 
                                          "Climate Change Governance"), amt = c(134, 3158, 91, 74, 2386, 
                                                                                528, 312, 252, 262, 1071, 519, 231, 52, 25, 32, 45, 23, 574, 
                                                                                15, 15, 88)), row.names = c(NA, 21L), class = "data.frame")
z$lab <- factor(z$no, labels = z$sector)
mycol <- colors()[444:500]
barplot(amt~lab, data = z, width = 4, space = 0.2, main = 'Zimbabwe budget by sector', xlab = 'Economic sectors', ylab = 'Amount in US $ millions', 
        col = mycol, cex.names = 0.6, horiz = F, las = 2)
legend('topright', legend=z$lab, fill = mycol, cex = 0.35, text.font = 3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`barplot` has builtin arguments for the legend, why not using them? Next, for the data using the `height=` argument is probably better, so the bars appear in the same order as in the table, use `beside` instead of `horiz` then; you can use `names.arg=` for the labels then, but they are actually superfluous because of the legend.

You definitely need more distinguishable colors, I use `rainbow` here.

Next, for the legend, just define `legend.text=`, and in `args.legend=` just put all the arguments you are used to from `legend()` in a `list`.

For better consistency I use the `png` device and not the one from Rstudio, which I think is more of a preview window.

Et voilá!

```
png('Rplot001.png', 800, 600)
barplot(z$am, beside=TRUE, col=rainbow(nrow(z), s=.6, v=.8),
        names.arg=z$sector,  ## just for demo, should be deleted
        legend.text=z$sector, args.legend=list(x='topright', cex=.9),
        width=4, space=0.2, main='Zimbabwe budget by sector', 
        xlab='Economic sectors', ylab='Amount in US $ millions', 
        cex.names=0.6, las=2)
dev.off()
```

[image]

**Note:** If you really want nice labels, check out my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70542204/6574038).

Comment: You have really helped me here. So I was able to understand your code. It took quite some reading and work, especially thoroughly learning the legend.text and args.legend functions. However, for the colors, the randomcoloR package came in handy. For the issue of overlapping labels, I will try to learn that another day.